# How to add an additional data member "number" to Account class?

Tags: c++

I am a little confused with syntax I guess. I am needing help on adding an addtional data member to class account called number. How would I do that?? I have tried adding an addtional data member called number that will represent an unique account number. The data meber will be used to locate the account so there will need to be a consturctor/or edit the constructors and "display" method.

Here is the code for Account.h:

```
#define START_BALANCE 500.0
#define START_INTEREST_RATE 0.0175
// define Account class
class Account
{
private:
     double balance;
     doube interestRate;
public:
    // constructor with default values
    // set to default values if value(s) is/are not valid
    Account(double initialBalance, double initialInterestRate);
    // observers
    double getBalance() const; // return balance
    double getInterestRate() const; // return interestRate
    void displayAccountInformation() const; // display formatted account information through cout
    // transformers
    bool deposit(double amount);
    // disposit amount into account
    // return false if unsuccessful (amount invalid, balance not changed)
    //        true otherwise
    bool withdraw(double amount);
    // withdraw amount from account
    // return false if unsuccessful (amount invalid, balance not changed)
    //        true otherwise
    void applyInterest(); // apply interestRate to balance
    bool setInterestRate(double newRate);
    // change interestRate to newRate
    // return false if unsuccessful (newRate invalid, interestRate not changed)
    //        true otherwise
    bool setBalance(double newBalance);
    // change balance to newBalance
    // return false if unsuccessful (newBalance invalid, balance not changed)
    //        true otherwise

}; // end Account

#endif
```

and here is the code for Account.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Account.h"
#include "ListDA.h"
using namespace std;

// constructor with default values
// set to default values if value(s) is/are not valid
Account::Account(double initialBalance = START_BALANCE, double initialInterestRate = START_INTEREST_RATE)
{
    if (initialBalance >= 0)
        balance = initialBalance;
    else // initialBalance < 0
        balance = START_BALANCE;
    if (initialInterestRate >= 0 && initialInterestRate < 1)
        interestRate = initialInterestRate;
    else // initialInterestRate >= 1 or initialInterestRate < 0
        interestRate = START_INTEREST_RATE;
} // end Account

// observers
double Account::getBalance() const
// return balance
{
    return balance;
} // end getBalance

double Account::getInterestRate() const
// return interestRate
{
    return interestRate;
} // end getInterestRate

void Account::displayAccountInformation() const
// display formatted account information through cout
{
    cout << "Account Information" << endl
         << "Current Balance: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << balance << endl
         << "Interest Rate: " << interestRate * 100 << "%" << endl;
} // end displayAccountInformation

// transformers
bool Account::deposit(double amount)
// disposit amount into account
// return false if unsuccessful (amount invalid, balance not changed)
//        true otherwise
{
    if (amount < 0) // invalid amount
        return false;
    balance += amount;
    return true;
} // end deposit

bool Account::withdraw(double amount)
// withdraw amount from account
// return false if unsuccessful (amount invalid, balance not changed)
//        true otherwise
{
    if (amount < 0 || amount > balance) // invalid amount
        return false;
    balance -= amount;
    return true;
} // end withdraw

void Account::applyInterest()
// apply interestRate to balance
{
    balance *= 1.0 + interestRate;
} // end applyInterest

bool Account::setInterestRate(double newRate)
// change interestRate to newRate
// return false if unsuccessful (newRate invalid, interestRate not changed)
//        true otherwise
{
    if (newRate < 0 || newRate >= 1) // invalid newRate
        return false;
    interestRate = newRate;
    return true;
} // end setInterestRate

bool Account::setBalance(double newBalance)
// change balance to newBalance
// return false if unsuccessful (newBalance invalid, balance not changed)
//        true otherwise
{
    if (newBalance < 0) // invalid balance
        return false;
    balance = newBalance;
    return true;

} // end setBalance
```

Any advise helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Doubles to represent money? In this economy?

Comment: This "question" isn't in quite the right form. What are you asking? We need a clear question, something that presents a more or less specific problem and can be answered in a useful manner. Are you looking for code review? There's a StackExchange for that. Is this homework?

Comment: No, I am asking how to to add an addtional member to class Account. I stated that above.

Comment: You didn't state the problem you're running into.

Comment: Yeah, I did. The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to add the addtional data member. I stated that above.

Comment: By commenting `// return interestRate` and ` // end getInterestRate` you only make the code horribly unreadable. I mean, if the body of the function says `return interestRate;`, what does commenting the exact same line give you?

Answer (score 0):

`balance` is a data member, right? And you have a getter and a setter for `balance`, right?

So, you would add similar items for the account number except you probably would use an `int` or a `long`.

Then you need to decide how you want to initialize this new member. One way would be to add it as an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want some kind of unique account Id that will be a instance variable in your class right? What you have is a good start, and then you just set it in the cunstructor and create set/get functions like this one:

header:

```
class Account {
    private:
    double accountId; // or number (which you should not call it. makes no sense)
    ....

    public:

    Account(...) {
        this->accountId = some unique number or something... 
    }

    double getAccountId() const {
         return this->accountId; // number
    }
    void setAccountId(double aid) {
         this->accountId = aid;
    }
    ....
};
```

However, I dont think you will need a set function if you really want the number to be unique and not be edited by the user (for example).

Then you have to ask yourself to what degree of uniqueness the Id has to be. If we are talking small numbers of accounts and no big damage if a few id's happened to be the same, I would not waste to much energy on it. For example, when apple are storing their customers, the Id for a customer has to be as unique as possible, otherwise a lot of horrible things can happen. This however can consume a lot of space if you need to store large unique strings.

What you can do is either use rand() (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) to generate a random rumber and combine it with some other string/number assosiated with the account, or just use the current date + time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's homework...nevertheless I'll give Lea a hand.

Lea, **data members** are the lines that look like `double balance;` and `double interestRate;`. They are just data, as opposed to the **methods** that have parentheses at the end like `double getBalance() const;` or `void applyInterest();`